# How to ensure at least one child element exists via XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

How can I ensure than at least one of `location`'s child elements (`locality`, `wkt`) is specified when the `location` element is included in an XML?

```
<xs:element name="location" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:group ref="cs:locationGroup"></xs:group>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Definition of `locationGroup`:

```
<xs:group name="locationGroup">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="locality" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="wkt" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:all>
</xs:group>
```

The version of my XSD is 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a small number of possible child elements, simply define a `xs:choice` of the allowed combinations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="location">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:group ref="locationGroup"></xs:group>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:group name="locationGroup">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="locality"/>
        <xs:element name="wkt" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="wkt"/>
        <xs:element name="locality" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

Note that this approach

- requires one or both of `locality` or `wkt` to be present
- allows any order when both are present
- works in both XSD 1.0 (and 1.1)

as requested.

Comment: ...is there a solution for the scalability problem this solution presents with large numbers of elements?

Comment: Yes, if XSD 1.1 doesn't help in your particular case, the solution to the permutations problem is to allow an order.  Unorderedness is overrated.